# How to get a full list of user's in-app purchases/transactions from iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, store

Here is my situation: in my app I have a set of consumable in-app purchases. All purchases sent to server to be validated and activated. But there is a possibility to encounter situation when user performed a purchase (paid money) but something happens during purchase activation (lost connection, server error, etc). In result both app and server do not know about purchase (lets take situation that app lost purchase data for some reason). So I need to get user's purchases/transaction from app store.

I've tried `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` 
but it does not return consumable purchases.

Is there any way to get a list of all purchases/transactions from app store?

Comment: Just to say that once the user has paid money they are always able to restore transactions. At a basic level they will be told they have already purchased when they try to purchase again, but you should implement a restore purchases button in addition (in fact Apple will reject any apps without this now). It isn't possible for someone to pay money and effectively go into a void.

Comment: Dear GuybrushThreepwood, have you read the situation? it is CONSUMABLE purchases. They are not present in restore (restoreCompletedTransactions) so that button you suggest is 100% useless. We need a transaction history list with all user's purchases for our app

Comment: I think you can do that only by having a separate server to register and remember consumable purchases, that also usually requires some form of user login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities: 
1) If the interaction fails with your server, don't finish the transaction (ie, don't remove the transaction from the queue). That way your transaction observer will get it again and you can try your server again.
2) Finish the transaction, but store enough info on the app (eg, NSUserDefaults) to try again with the server later. You can start a timer that will try again later.